# Weather Python RPI

Tags: python

I am making a weather program with Python on the Pi.

```
import geocoder

address = raw_input("City, State: ")

g = geocoder.google('address')
print g.latlng
```

When I run the code, I input 'San Francisco, CA' and it outputs coords for Rhode Island. It even happens with 'New York City, NY'.

However, if I edit the code like this:

```
g = geocoder.google('San Francisco, CA')
```

and

```
g = geocoder.google('New York City, NY')
```

it outputs the correct coordinates.

Now how can I make it so that the raw_input will work?

Comment: change this line:g = geocoder.google('address') to g = geocoder.google(address)

Comment: This is not specific to the Pi. General programming questions should be asked on our sister site http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: I tried posting in StackOverflow but it said that I had to wait 2 days before posting another question.

Comment: That may be the case, but it does not mean you should post here.

Comment: Can I move it to there? Or will I have to delete this

Comment: No need to delete it, it will stay here but future progrmmingquestions should be asked there not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to

```
google(address)
```

not

```
google('address')
```

When you specify the string 'address', you're actually looking for a place called 'address', rather than the value that's stored in the variable address. Google interprets it as this place:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Address,+3+Sweet+Fern+Ln,+Coventry,+RI+02816/@41.6763577,-71.5394068,17z